# Using sed to extract strings from a text file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text data in this form:

```
^Well/Well[ADV]+ADV ^John/John[N]+N ^has/have[V]+V+3sg+PRES ^a/a[ART]
^quite/quite[ADV]+ADV ^different/different[ADJ]+ADJ ^not/not[PART]
^necessarily/necessarily[ADV]+ADV ^more/more[ADV]+ADV
^elaborated/elaborate[V]+V+PPART ^theology/theology[N]+N *edu$
```

And I want it to be processed to this form:

```
Well John have a quite different not necessarily more elaborate theology
```

Basically, I need every string between the starting character `/` and the ending character `[`.

Here is what I tried, but I just get empty files...

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in probe/*.txt

do sed '///,/[/d' $file > $file.aa

mv $file.aa $file

done
```

Comment: Try escaping your start char: `///` -> `/\//`

Comment: that still gives me empty files :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F/ -v RS=^ -v ORS=' ' '{print $1}' file

Well John has a quite different not necessarily more elaborated theology
```

**Explanation** set record separator (RS) to `^` to separate your logical groups, also set the field separator (FS) to `/` and print the first field as your requirement.  Finally, setting the output field separator (OFS) to space (instead of the default new line) keeps the extracted fields on the same line.

Comment: yes that works, thank you!! if you could explain to me what the different arguments mean i would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep and Perl compatible regular expressions (`-P`):

```
$ echo $(grep -Po '(?<=/)[^[]*' infile)
Well John have a quite different not necessarily more elaborate theology
```

`-o` retains just the matches, `(?<=/)` is a positive look-behind ("make sure there is a `/`, but don't include it in the match"), and `[^[]*` is "a sequence of characters other than `[`".

`grep -Po` prints one match per line; by using the output of grep as arguments to `echo`, we convert the newlines into spaces (could also be done by piping to `tr '\n' ' '`).

Comment: typo... should be `'(?<=/)[^[]*'`.. an extra ``/`` left at start.. can also use `'/\K[^[]*'`

Comment: @sundeep I had `\K` at first, that's where the spare `/` came from ;) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
 cat file|grep -oE "\/[^\[]*\[" |sed -e 's#^/##' -e 's/\[$//' | tr -s "\n" " "
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)